# I think my chocolate fudge is seizing?

Tags: chocolate, fudge

new here and amateur home cook.

I'm trying new fudge recipes and got one down that works extremely well when I'm not using chocolate. When I use chocolate, it... Seizes I think. It becomes crumbly without becoming crystalized.

Recipe is:

1. Bring  6oz. evaporated milk and 1.5c sugar to a boil until 224°F (I live a mile above sea level)
2. Pour it onto a greased pan (greased with vegetable or canola oil) that has been sitting in the freezer and throw that into the freezer asap
3. In a stand mixer bowl, add 5-7oz. of morsels (semisweet chocolate, butterscotch, peanut butter, etc), 6 tbs. of room temp unsalted butter, pinch of salt, and dash of vanilla extract. Set aside.
4. When the syrup is at 120-130°F, pour into the bowl with stuff in it and mix on low until combined. With the peanut butter morsels, I was able to let it go for a while and made some night light and fluffy fudge.

The chocolate fudge, however, comes out crumbly for some reason. I use basic semisweet morsels. One instance was clearly the chocolate seizing; when I pressed it into a pan, all the fat from the butter seeped to the surface like a sponge. Another time, I put the butter in the pan with the milk and sugar, and it still became crumbly through the fat didn't seep out almost at all.

Help? I've tried a lot of testing on the sugar syrup up to this point practicing the recipe and have since had the chocolate fudge attempts fail everytime.

EDIT: Solved! I simply pre-melt the chocolate morsels, make sure the syrup reaches 50°C/120°F, mix together and incorporate butter after the syrup and chocolate are mixed fully! It's been consistently working well.

Comment: Are you saying this isn't a chocolate fudge recipe? If it is, can you give the source if online?

Comment: It is, it's one I've cobbled together from looking at tons of recipes and looking into the science behind sugar crystal formation.

Comment: You mention looking into sugar crystal formation, but have you looked into chocolate crystal formation? Chocolate has crystals as well, and I wonder if its the "tempering" of the chocolate here that's getting you into trouble. 120-130F is a bit hot for chocolate.